# What pattern-matching algorithm is this?

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I was reading the book Theory & Problems Of Data Struc (Seymour Lipschuz).

Let me provide an image of the section I was reading.[image: link of this book].

This section of the book talks about a pattern-matching algorithm named "Second Patter-Matching Algorithm".

What algorithm is this? Is this Boyer-Moore or KMP or Horspool or what?

Or, is this any new algorithm produced by the author?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this without the book?

Comment: Right, so we know the title of the book, but how does that help in identifying an algorithm IN the book? Do you think all programmers own a copy?

Comment: I have clicked the link, it is just the book cover and links to buy it. [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hTlwC.png).

Comment: I think Google has blocked the book in your country. This book is hosted in GoogleBooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is the [KMP](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html) algorithm.  KMP constructs a "failure table" that is essentially an automaton saying "if you mismatch on a particular character, how much of the pattern string can you still be matching?"  It also does a preprocessing of the pattern and not the string being matched.  Moreover, if you look at the Aho-Corasick algorithm, which is a generalization of KMP, it constructs a more general version of this automaton that works on multiple patterns at once.  Consequently, I'm pretty sure that you're looking at KMP.